# Looking for a ADSL/VDSL Router that support bandwidth controlling

Tags: networking, router

First of all I don't know much about networking. So I will try to elaborate my question as much as I can. I have a limited broadband connection with 21 mbps of download speed. There are 4 devices connecting wirelessly to the router and 1 desktop computer connected via a LAN cable. Since I have a limited amount of data per month, I want to limit the bandwidth seperatly among those devices as follows.

1. LAN - Desktop - Maximum 8 mbps
2. WIFI - Laptop - Maximum 8 mbps
3. WIFI - Smartphone 1 - Maximum 2 mbps
4. WIFI - Smartphone 2 - Maximum 2 mbps
5. WIFI - Smartphone 3 - Maximum 2 mbps

Currently I'm using a cheap router given by my ISP and it doesn't support bandwidth controlling. I'm still not sure even this is possible so I would appreciate if anyone can suggest me a router for home use which can fulfill my need.

P.S.

Well, I ended up getting a TP-Link router (TD-W8968). It can easily be configured with IPTV and there is a seperate WIFI access point for guest users which allows to assign limited bandwidth for all the guest users. So I decided to connect all the mobile devices via its guest access point  and my desktop and laptop with prioritized minimum and maximum bandwidth limits. Now I've noticed that the internet speed is not consistent all the time. I've set the guest account bandwidth to 2mbps  but most of the time I'm getting only around 400-500kbps. sometimes it's just stops working. @Alphy13 Maybe you're right, maybe I am setting so many rules or maybe I've messed up the router settings due to lack of knowledge about networking.

Comment: Try using a better router. The TD-W8968 is only B/G/N. (Wifi 3) You are likely to see an improvement from a $60 router that is AC (Wifi 5) or AX (Wifi 6). Both of these use the 5GHz band and **have better standards for handling multiple devices at the same time**. Sorry you already bought the other, but I think you will find it worth it to get a newer router. Just dont go overkill and spend $200, its not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Archer AX10](https://smile.amazon.com/TP-Link-Wifi-AX1500-Smart-Router/dp/B07ZSDR49S/). It has bandwidth control and is a very well priced Wifi 6 router.

Wifi 6 (802.11ax) is the newest standard. Most of the routers out there are still on Wifi 5 (802.11ac) or lower.

It is important to note that setting bandwidth limits will allow you regulate each device's max speed, but this will likely cause more problems than it solves. While your speed will be slower, you will likely not decrease your overall usage. Typically, your router is fairly good at balancing the load on each of your devices and it is better not to set hard rules like this.

Check with your ISP to see what your data cap is. They may have a better way to track where you are in your usage for that pay period. However, unless you are on satellite internet, your data cap is usually high enough you do not need to monitor it.